# python program to sort a list in ascending order without using the sort function

Tags: python, loops, sorting

//it only works for numbers
//i want it to work for string as well

```
def method(list):
   for i in range(len(list)):
      for j in range(i+1,len(list)):
          if list[i]>list[j]:
                list[i],list[j]=list[j],list[i]
return list
```

Comment: Your code is working for me for the string as well. Just the error is that the ```return``` statement should be inside the function definition. You have written it outside the function scope. You can correct it by indenting the ```return``` statement. Also please avoid defining the list name by word ```list```. It is a keyword in python.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and will be able to sort a list of strings as well.

You just need to make small fixes . Try the below code :

```
def my_sorting(input_list):
   for i in range(len(input_list)):
      for j in range(i+1,len(input_list)):
          if input_list[i] > input_list[j]:
              input_list[i],input_list[j] = input_list[j],input_list[i]
   return input_list
```

**Sample input/output :**

Input --->  `input_list = ["zas", "app", "zaa", "abc", "aaz"]`

Output ---> `['aaz', 'abc', 'app', 'zaa', 'zas']`